# Not able to center Loading Spinner in my React application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a website, and I have added a spinner that loads when the website is loading. Note that I am using react-router-dom with this.

The router works, but it is not displayed as intended. I am unable to centralize it, even with `margin, left: 50%` and the `<center>` tag.

Take a look at my code:

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <style>
      .loader {
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-top: 25%;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      }

      @keyframes spin {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <center>
      <div class="loader-container" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%">
        <div class="loader"></div>
      </div>
    </center>
```

snippet on the working of the spinner:

```
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  function fakeRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2500));
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fakeRequest().then(() => {
      const el = document.querySelector(".loader-container");
      if (el) {
        el.remove();
        setLoading(!isLoading);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null;
  }
```

router (app.js):

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Also, just a doubt, is it possible to remove the layout when it loads?

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS issue. Just remove your inline styles on `loader-container` and update your margins on `.loader` as below:

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 25% auto 0 auto;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

And if you want to remove the style tag for the loader with it, just move  your `<style>` inside `loader-container`. And you don't need the center `<center>` tag anymore.